# Trying to create a color change application using the DOM in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

This is the Javascript Code. The HTML is just a button tag and the link to a specific stylesheet and the script.

```
  let color = ["#F1FF06", "#A5FF06", "#59FF06", "#FF6506", "#FF1E06", "#B0736C", "#B0A56C", "#06EA9D", "#06EA9D", "#06EA9D","#98D8DE","#D098D1", "#770C79","#000000","#2F062E", "#F6F6F6"]
  let i = 0;
  document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click",  function(){
    i = i < color.length ? ++1 : 0;
  document.querySelector("body").style.background = color[i];
  })
```

Comment: And the problem/question is?

Comment: `1 !== i` -> `++i`

Comment: Please write your problem statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this snippet resolves the problem ;) The ++ in true of ternary if statement with color.length was doing nothing, so i changed it to ++i

```js
  let color = ["#F1FF06", "#A5FF06", "#59FF06", "#FF6506", "#FF1E06", "#B0736C", "#B0A56C", "#06EA9D", "#06EA9D", "#06EA9D","#98D8DE","#D098D1", "#770C79","#000000","#2F062E", "#F6F6F6"]
  let i = 0;
  document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click",  function(){
    i = i < color.length ? ++i : 0;

  document.querySelector("body").style.background = color[i];
  })
```

```html
<body>
  <button>
    change color
  </button>
</body>
```

Comment: What did you change? And why?

Comment: the ++ in true of ternary statement was doing nothing, so i changed it to ++i

Comment: Please add it to your answer. For future readers it should not be necessary to read all comments to understand an answer/question.